# Using ASP.NET MVC 2, StructureMap, Fluent NHibernate, and PostgreSQL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, postgresql, fluent-nhibernate, structuremap

I am using the above combo in a new web app Im doing just to try to learn to build new stuff to expand my knowledge. Im hoping to go live if I do a good job.. Im kind of new at MVC and the other products so I was trying to find a link to a good tutorial that set all of these up together. If anyone knows of one or maybe 2 that set up 3 of them together I would appreciate it.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The CodeCampServer (http://codecampserver.codeplex.com/) uses ASP.Net MVC 2, Structuremap and Fluent NHibernate together. For PostgreSQL there shouldn't be anything special for Fluent NHibernate aside from the configuration settings, so any good PostgreSQL getting started guide should do you just fine.

Comment: I went to check that out, but as I am kind of a newer person to the enterprise development stuff, that was way over my head. I need something simpler to start out with cause I mainly want to actually learn how to do all of the plumbing in the meantime..

Comment: I'm not aware of a tutorial that specifically uses these technologies, but I'd recommend finding tutorials for each and once you have a grasp on them individually then you should be able to put them together by yourself.